# Tensorflow2.2.0 ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to update cache while training a UNet. I'm rewriting some function from tf=2.13.0 to 2.2.0 because the latter is the only available version on my GPU cluster.

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.7.4
- Tensorflow 2.2.0

```py
class Distance(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name='DistanceMetric', distance='cm', sigma=2.5, data_size=None,
                 validation_size=None, points=None, point=None, percentile=None):
        super(Distance, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.counter = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, dtype=tf.int32)
        self.distance = distance
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.percentile = percentile
        if percentile is not None and point is not None:
            assert (type(percentile) == float)
            self.percentile_idx = tf.Variable(tf.cast(tf.round(percentile * validation_size), dtype=tf.int32))
        else:
            self.percentile_idx = None
        self.point = point
        self.points = points
        self.cache = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros([validation_size, points]),
                                 shape=[validation_size, points])
        print('cache shape', self.cache.shape)
        self.val_size = validation_size


    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        n, h, w, p = tf.shape(y_pred)[0], tf.shape(y_pred)[1], tf.shape(y_pred)[2], tf.shape(y_pred)[3]
        # print('y true', y_true)
        y_true = normal_distribution(self.sigma, y_true[:, :, 0], y_true[:, :, 1], h=h, w=w, n=n, p=p)
        # print('y true', y_true)

        if self.distance == 'cm':
            x1, y1 = cm(y_true, h=h, w=w, n=n, p=p)
            x2, y2 = cm(y_pred, h=h, w=w, n=n, p=p)
            d = ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5
            # print('d shape before', d.shape)
            d = d[:, :, 0]
            # print('d shape after ', d.shape)
        elif self.distance == 'argmax':
            d = (tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(((argmax_2d(y_true) - argmax_2d(y_pred)) ** 2), axis=1),
                         dtype=tf.float32)) ** 0.5

        temp = tf.minimum(self.counter + n, self.val_size-1)
        condition = tf.math.less_equal(self.counter, self.val_size)
        def true_fn():
            with tf.control_dependencies([self.cache[self.counter:temp, :].assign(d[0:(temp-self.counter), :])]):
            # self.cache[self.counter:temp, :].assign(d[0:(temp-self.counter), :])
                return self.cache
        def false_fn():
            return self.cache
        # self.cache = tf.cond(condition, self.cache[self.counter:temp, :].assign(d[0:(temp-self.counter), :]), self.cache)
        self.cache = tf.cond(condition, true_fn, false_fn)

        self.counter.assign(self.counter + n)

    def result(self):
        if self.percentile_idx is not None:
            temp = tf.sort(self.cache[:self.val_size, self.point], axis=0, direction='ASCENDING')
            return temp[self.percentile_idx]
        elif self.point is not None:
            return tf.reduce_mean(self.cache[:, self.point], axis=0)
        else:
            return tf.reduce_mean(self.cache, axis=None)

    def reset_states(self):
        self.cache.assign(tf.zeros_like(self.cache))
        self.counter.assign(0)
        if self.percentile is not None and self.point is not None:
            self.percentile_idx.assign(tf.cast(self.val_size * self.percentile, dtype=tf.int32))
```

`self.cache` should be a tf.Variable (see def **init**), but I can't slice it to add new values.

```
ValueError: in user code:

/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
    outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_re$
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_r$
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:543 train_step  **
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:411 update_state
    metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p)
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:90 decorated
    update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
/trinity/home/r084755/DRF_AI/distal-radius-fractures-x-pa-and-lateral-to-clinic/Code files/LandmarkDetection.py:163 update_state
    self.cache = tf.cond(condition, true_fn, false_fn)
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py:1392 cond_for_tf_v2
    return cond(pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, strict=True, name=name)
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py:507 new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py:1177 cond
    return cond_v2.cond_v2(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/cond_v2.py:84 cond_v2
    op_return_value=pred)
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:981 func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
/trinity/home/r084755/DRF_AI/distal-radius-fractures-x-pa-and-lateral-to-clinic/Code files/LandmarkDetection.py:157 true_fn
    with tf.control_dependencies([self.cache[self.counter:temp, :].assign(d[0:(temp-self.counter), :])]):
/opt/ohpc/pub/easybuild/software/TensorFlow/2.2.0-fosscuda-2019b-Python-3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:1160 assign
    raise ValueError("Sliced assignment is only supported for variables")

ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables
```

Please can somebody help me. I'm unexperienced with tf. I've tried many options, but keep running into new issues.